# Why output of .imshow is discontinous?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

dear humans and AI (you never know)!

If i create NumPy array such as following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
z = np.random.randint(20, 90, size=(100,1))
z = np.sort(z)
a = np.full((100,100),1)
a[z,x] = 2
plt.imshow(a, aspect='auto')
```

I see all the pixels

But, if I increase the number of samples to 1000:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1000)
z = np.random.randint(200, 900, size=(1000,1))
z = np.sort(z)
a = np.full((1000,1000),1)
a[z,x] = 2
plt.imshow(a, aspect='auto')
```

I see huge gaps between pixels like here.

[image: like here]

How can I fix that, so I would have an output like this?

[image: like this]?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think this is not a duplicate of the question you linked. The problem here seems not to be about pixels not being shown, but instead pixels defining a line without being connected, i.e. an `ax.plot()` call would probably solve the issue. This question also seems to be a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45750896/2454357)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, maybe I'm completely missing something here, but (1) the code in the question should not produce any line at all, (2) If it was to produce a line, you would see only some pixels of it, due to the issue from [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605291/some-values-of-matrix-do-not-appear-in-the-plot-by-matplotlib). The answer to the linked question also already tells that plotting a line may be a good alternative. Of course if the question is edited as to provide a clear problem description, it can be reopened.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ok, point taken :)